# Постановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Столкнулся на Тотальном диктанте с таким предложением:

> > Через мгновение раздается музыка **—** хриплая, заикающаяся, и всё же — музыка.

Чем обусловлено первое тире? Что оно отделяет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Чем обусловлено первое тире? Что оно
> отделяет?

По-моему, это:

> **§ 85.** **Присоединительные члены предложения**, не имеющие специальных
> вводящих слов и выступающие в качестве
> разъясняющих добавочных сообщений,
> **отделяются знаком тире.** Они стоят в конце предложения...
>
> http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Comment: Не вижу присоединения. Скорее поясняющее согласованное определение в конце предложения. По ссылке Славы:  § 51. Определения, стоящие в конце предложения, как нераспространенные, так и с зависимыми словами, могут отделяться знаком тире. Такие определения имеют пояснительно-уточняющее значение: От результатов этой борьбы зависит, в конечном счете, человеческое счастье — настоящее и будущее (Аст.); Опять пахло дымом, но только это был иной запах — древесный, сухой, утренний (Шукш.).

Comment: 

Людмила писала: "Определения, стоящие в конце предложения..."

===

А разве в разбираемом предложении определения "хриплая, заикающаяся" стоят В КОНЦЕ предложения?

Comment: Да, в конце, потому что дальше присоединительная конструкция" и всё же — музыка". Как хотите его считайте - оборотом или отдельным присоединительным неполным предложением, но это уже присоединение,а не основная информация.

Comment: Кстати, там варианты в пунктуации. Возможна и  запятая  вместо первого тире,и второе можно не ставить. Сейчас вот нашла  разбор диктанта. http://totaldict.ru/upload/files/%D0%A2%D0%94%202015%202%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8.pdf

Comment: Посмотрел этот "разбор". Посмеялся... И удивился: вроде бы и люди писали его грамотные, да...

После увиденной в "разборе" ссылки на  § 46.1 дальше можно было бы уже ничего и не читать.

Comment: Людмила, а в каком пункте сказано, что там возможно запятая после первого тире?

Comment: Слава, согласен! На этот раз мне кажется, они переборщили с разбором. Интересно, а были ли такие, которые делали ошибки в таких словах,как ''озеро'', ''на воде'' и т.д. Примитив! Прошлый разбор достаточно серьезным!

Answer (score 0):

Интересно то, что присоединительные члены мы часто не отличаем от вставных конструкций, а это все-таки не одно и то же. Присоединительные члены – это обособленные с помощью тире, а не запятой различные члены предложения, в то время как  вставка может быть совершенно отдельной синтаксической конструкцией.

Не похоже на вставку сочетание «хриплая, заикающаяся, и всё же — музыка», и передает оно не добавочное, а основное содержание сообщения, Это, скорее, не второй план, а актуализация содержания, выделение его  в отдельную часть.

Можно перестроить предложение: «Через мгновение раздается музыка — хриплая, заикающаяся, непохожая на себя и всё же музыка». Думается, что перед нами обособленное приложение как цельное выражение, которое уже внутри себя имеет сложное строении и содержит присоединительную часть (присоединительный союз И и обозначение авторской паузы с помощью тире).